# If abstract base class is an interface, is it obligatory to call base class constructor in derived class constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, class-design, abstract-class

```
class AbstractQuery {
    virtual bool isCanBeExecuted()=0;
public:
    AbstractQuery() {}
    virtual bool Execute()=0;
};

class DropTableQuery: public AbstractQuery {
    vector< std::pair< string, string> > QueryContent;
    QueryValidate qv;
public:
    explicit DropTableQuery(const string& qr): AbstractQuery(), qv(qr) {}
    bool Execute();
};
```

Is it necessary to call base contructor in derived class constructor?

Comment: Please use proper code formating so we can read your snippet properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, in fact for it is unnecessary for the base class to have an explicitly defined constructor (though make sure you have a virtual destructor).

So for a typical interface you could have something like this:

```
class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface() {}
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};
```

EDIT: Here's a reason why you should have a virtual destructor:

```
MyInterface* iface = GetMeSomeThingThatSupportsInterface();
delete iface; // this is undefined behaviour if MyInterface doesn't have a virtual destructor
```

Comment: Here is a more direct question to explain your reasons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270917/why-should-i-declare-a-virtual-destructor-for-an-abstract-class-in-c.

Answer (score 4):

It is **never** obligatory to explicitly call the base class constructor, unless it has parameters. The compiler will call the constructor automatically. Theoretically the base class still has a constructor, but the compiler may optimize it away into non-existence if it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in the example you provided. The base class' default constructors will be called automatically in the same order that the base classes are declared, before any member of the derived class is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If the base class's constructor does not need any parameters, you do not need to call it in the derived class since it is called as a default constructor. However you need to provide a virtual destructor for your base class even if it is empty. Otherwise compiler will generate a default destructor which is non-virtual by default.