# why to declare a virtual destructor C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I declare a virtual destructor for an abstract class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270917/why-should-i-declare-a-virtual-destructor-for-an-abstract-class-in-c)

I inherited some code here I'm trying to understand, and the header file is:

```
class RemoteNotify : public virtual ServiceObject, public virtual RemoteMsg{
      RemoveNotify();
      virtual ~RemoveNotify();
      /* more code down here */
}
```

I would like to know why someone would declare a `virtual` destructor?

Comment: So that deleting a pointer-to-base calls the most-derived dtor.

Comment: You should probably read some introductory text on C++

Comment: On this regard, probably the correct question should be: why doesn't the compiler enforce a virtual destructor if the class has virtual members ?

Comment: @StefanoBorini: I would assume that is based on the principle  that you don't pay for things you don't need. Just because you have virtual members does not mean that you absolutely need a virtual destructor (you might always know the correct type at the point of deletion. Of course there is nothing keeping the compiler from warning in this case.