# Is it possible to typecast an initializer_list in C++?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have an initializer_list of char and want to typecast it to an initializer_list of unsigned char:

```
// This code doesn't work, and it's used just as an example
reinterpret_cast<initializer_list<unsigned char>>(initializer_list<char>);
```

How would I do this?

**Edit:**

Here's what I'm trying to do:

As I'm new to C++, I've been trying to create random programs to learn it. My current goal is to have a class that inherits from basic_string to implement ISO 8859-1.
But one of the constructors from basic_string is defined as

```
basic_string(initializer_list<charT> il, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
```

Thus, to implement the following functionality (that I currently see no use, I'm just trying to implement everything from the class)

```
// ISO_8859_1_String is a basic_string<unsigned char, ..., ...>
// where "..." are the other parameters, which are omitted to improve readability 
ISO_8859_1_String testString{'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

I have to create a constructor that receives an initializer_list of characters and translates it to the character type of ISO_8859_1_String, which is unsigned char. There's where this question enters.

```
ISO_8859_1_String(initializer_list<char> il, 
                  const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()):
    basic_string<unsigned char, ..., ...>
                 (magicFunctionToConvertCharILToUnCharIL(il), alloc){}
```

Is there a way I can do this, maybe using an auxiliary function to convert the initializer_list to something else, and then to the desired initializer_list?

**Solution:**

As pointed out by @Brian, I could use the iterators from initializer_list to call the following constructor of basic_string:

```
template <class InputIterator>
    basic_string  (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
             const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

So I modified my constructor to:

```
ISO_8859_1_String(initializer_list<char> il, 
                  const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()):
    basic_string<unsigned char, ..., ...>
                 (std::begin(il), std::end(il), alloc){}
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" - what do you mean?

Comment: sure about the `reinterpret_cast<>`??

Comment: I mean this: error: invalid cast from type ‘std::initializer_list<char>’ to type ‘std::initializer_list<unsigned char>’

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270917/why-should-i-declare-a-virtual-destructor-for-an-abstract-class-in-c. Inheriting from basic_string is not intended or recommended and can lead to serious problems. Do yourself the favor and step away from that solution, especially when you are learning C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the conversion you are trying to perform cannot be accomplished with a cast---at least, not safely. In addition, there are only three ways to create a new `std::initializer_list` object:

1. With the default constructor: `std::initializer_list<unsigned char> IL;`
2. With the braced-init-list syntax: `std::set<int> {1, 2, 3};`
3. By copying another initializer list of the same type: `std::initializer_list<int> IL; IL = {1, 2, 3};`

Pretty much the only reason initializer lists exist is for convenience when initializing. An initializer list is useless on its own. It sure isn't a great container. If you want to use an `initializer_list<char>` to initialize a container of `unsigned char`, use the usual range constructor.

```
std::initializer_list<char> IL {'a', 'b', 'c'};
std::vector<unsigned char> V(IL.begin(), IL.end());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Brian. Based on it, I guess I won't be able to complete my goal, but I've edited my question to point out exactly what I want from initializer_lists. Would you mind checking it out? By the way, if I were able to convert V (from your answer) to an initializer_list<unsigned char>, I'd be able to do what I wanted.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho, use the range constructor for `basic_string`. Just like I suggested in my answer. It's #7 here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/basic_string/

Answer (score 1):

std::string is not meant to be a base-class. It does not have a virtual destructor. Instead, it is a template class which you can specialize for your character type:

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> iso8859_1;
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, but if I wanted to use things like 'iso8859_1 str = "test"', I'd have to typecast by hand, like 'iso8859_1 str = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>("test")', but I wanted it to be "behind the scenes". That's why I inherited from basic_string<unsigned char> and then extended it's functionality to accept chars too.

Comment: You can give your basic_string specialization a constructor accepting a const char* and hide the conversion therein. Inheriting from basic_string is just wrong and will give you undefined behavior if you ever delete a iso8859_1 object through a pointer to basic_string. Do not do it.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should have a basic_string member inside the ISO class, which doesn't inherit (in this example) from anything, correct?

Comment: @DanielCarvalho Yes, either have a wrapper class with a basic_string<unsigned char> member, or have a template specialization.  You mentioned that you are just learning C++, so I think you have not learnt about template specialization so far. In this case, I would go with the member.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Later on today I'll be researching about template specialization. Thank you very much for your help! (unfortunately, I can't vote you up, because I don't have the required reputation)

Comment: so I decided to try template specialization, but I'm not being able to implement it. Would you mind giving me a tip? Here's what I have: namespace std{
  template<> class basic_string<unsigned char, char_traits<unsigned char>, allocator<unsigned char> >{
    public:
      // Constructor: From C-string, but assigning from char instead of unsigned char
      basic_string(const char* s, const basic_string::allocator_type& alloc = basic_string::allocator_type()):basicString(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s), alloc){}
  };
}

Comment: Could you post a complete example together with the error message or a more specific problem description? Maybe as a new question, because the comments do not work well with embedded code.

Comment: As requested, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530004/doesnt-template-specialization-inherit-members-functions