# Doesn't template specialization "inherit" members/functions?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm just starting with C++, and I'm trying to create a class that extends the functionalities of basic_string < unsigned char > to let it accept chars as arguments for the constructors too, and they'd be handled by casting them and calling the base constructors for basic_string.

I've been told to use template specialization for that, but I've been struggling with it, so I've created a simple extract of the current problem: how template specialization works:

```
template<typename T> class TestClass{
  public:
    // Sample constructor
    TestClass(const char* name){
      std::cout << "Created class " << name << std::endl;
    }
};

// Doesn't add any functionalities, just used as an example
template<> class TestClass<int>{};
```

As expected, if I use the following:

```
  TestClass<char> test = TestClass<char>("Test");
```

The file compiles, and the output is correct.

But if I use the following:

```
  TestClass<int> specializedTest = TestClass<int>("Specialized Test");
```

The file doesn't compile, throwing the following **error**:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:50:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘TestClass<int>::TestClass(const char [17])’
test.cpp:50:69: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:47:18: note: TestClass<int>::TestClass()
test.cpp:47:18: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
test.cpp:47:18: note: TestClass<int>::TestClass(const TestClass<int>&)
test.cpp:47:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [17]’ to ‘const TestClass<int>&’
```

**Question 1**: Shouldn't the specialized class inherit the TestClass's members and functions? Because if it doesn't, it looks to me that I'm just creating a class and "masking" it as the base class. i.e. (in pseudocode)

```
class SpecializedTestClass{/* Add class code here */};
typedef SpecializedTestClass TestClass<int>;
```

If not, why not? It makes sense for me that, if you're specializing a class, all classes members/functions should be kept unless they are specialized.

Maybe I'm just mixing template with class inheritance.

**Question 2**: Is this the best approach to my problem? (Combine the functionalities of basic_string< unsigned char > and basic_string< char > so that the data is stored as unsigned char, but can be assigned from char using typecasts.)

Comment: Looks like a default constructor for `TestClass` is expected somewhere else ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When you (explicitly or partially) specialize a class, your specialization is an entirely new template. The only thing it shares with the existing template is its name.

As to why, we can only guess. Two obvious reasons would be that it's fairly difficult (to the point that most compilers didn't implement the current partial specialization spec correctly for years after the standard was written) and that it's probably open to question (at best) whether it's desirable.

As far as this being the best approach: I doubt it, but I don't have a lot better suggestion to give either. Getting `string`/`basic_string` to deal nicely with `unsigned char` has been a problem almost since it was invented, and I haven't seen a way to deal with it yet that produces particularly good results.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of why I would prefer doing template specialization instead of creating a new class from scratch?

Comment: @DanielCarvalho: Probably the most common reason you'd do this would be to optimize existing code. You have code that already uses some template, and want to get it to use a new implementation when instantiated over a particular type. This lets you do what without rewriting the client code.

Comment: I'm not completely sold yet. I'll research a little bit more. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: +1 The current incarnation of templates was designed over the needs of the STL, and one of the usage examples that was provided in the language was `std::vector`. Clearly, `std::vector<bool>` does not (and should not) have the same members than the generic template, so I imagine that since the beginning it was clear that *inheriting* the generic template was not desirable.

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1: Shouldn't the specialized class inherit the TestClass's members and functions?

It doesn't, it is a completely unrelated type. This is intentional, consider `std::vector<T>` and `std::vector<bool>`, the member are completely different. Specialization is **not** extending the type, but rather providing a different type for a specific need. There is no *base* class in an specialization.

> Question 2: Is this the best approach to my problem?

I am not sure what the real problem to solve is. There is already an implicit conversion from `char` to `unsigned char`, so normal chars should be accepted in the interface… right? If what you mean is passing `const char*`, (i.e. pointers, not values), then you can provide that externally as a helper function:

```
basic_string<unsigned char> create(const char* s) {
   return basic_string<unsigned char>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(s));
}
```

Comment: Regarding question 2, I understand your approach, but I wanted to know if there's a way to do this using constructor delegation, because if I do your way I will have to create an auxiliary class just to add these constructors, and operator overloads. Also, I wanted the class to be a "copy" of string, so that if the user knows how to use string, then it would be able to use the unsigned_char_string class as if it were using string.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho: You need not create a new class, just free functions (as the one above) to forward to the constructors you want. I still don't quite see the need to have a `basic_string<unsigned char>` anyways. The very first thing that you are going to encounter is that it is just the opposite of a vocabulary type, you won't be able to use your type (`std::basic_string<unsigned char>` really) with almost any of the existing libraries or interfaces. You are trying hard to build incompatibilities...