# C++ inherit constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a class, `Tile`, that has a constructor with parameters of a `Color` object:

```
class Tile
{
public:
    static const int size = 32;

    Tile();
    Tile(Color &color);

    void render(int x, int y);

    Color getColor();

    ~Tile();
private:
    Color _color;
};
```

Then I have a subclass, `TileGrass`, which inherits `Tile`:

```
class TileGrass : public Tile
{
public:
    TileGrass();
    ~TileGrass();
};
```

Now the issue is that the `TileGrass` needs to inherit the `Tile` constructor with the Color parameters. But, the `TileGrass` object already knows what color it needs to give to the superclass, so I don't want to have to pass in a `Color` object when creating a new `TileGrass` object. In Java I can do something like this:

```
public class TileGrass extends Tile {

public TileGrass() {
    super(color object);
}
}
```

How can I do something like this in C++?

Comment: In C++(11) inheriting constructors means being able to call a constructor of the base class to build a derived object. Here you just want to call a specific base constructor inside the derived constructor, pretty standard thing...

Comment: @user3316633: Also, please note that `~Tile()` should be declared virtual.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270917/why-should-i-declare-a-virtual-destructor-for-an-abstract-class-in-c) for details on why.

Comment: @Edward only if you plan to use polymorphism

Answer (score 9):

Just call the relevant base class constructor in the initialization list:

```
class TileGrass : public Tile
{
 public:
  TileGrass() : Tile(some_color) 
  {
    // ....
  }

  ~TileGrass();
};
```

Comment: I believe this is actually called inheriting constructors in the ISO standard as well.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain Inheriting constructors refers to a different thing. For example, `using Tile::Tile` would let you construct `TileGrass t(some_color);` without having to declare and define `TileGrass(Color&)`.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain See [Inheriting constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors)