# How should I store templated functions in any container?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a templated Prob class that acts as a way to organize various programming problems from different problem sets.  The template is the problem number.  How would I go about storing different Prob objects in a vector or map?

Here is the class declaration:

```
template<int ProbNum>
class Prob 
{
    std::string 
    text(std::ostream& out) 
    {
        out << "Prob" << ((ProbNum < 10) ? "0" : "") << ProbNum << ": "; 
    }

    void solve(std::ostream& out);
};
```

So in other words if I want to declare an object for problem 1 of some problem set I would do

```
Prob<1> p1;
```

and then store that in a map or vector for later use so the user can call on it during runtime (since you cannot pass a runtime argument into a template).

Edit: I want to use this class as an abstract class for other Prob classes.

Edit2: Added more code for clarification.

Edit3:
Top half is Prob1.hpp

Bottom half is a driver file on how I want to use it.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Prob.hpp"

template<>
void
Prob<1>::solve(std::ostream& out)
{
    out << "solution to prob1";
}

/***************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Prob.hpp"

// Finished Problems
#include "Prob1.hpp"

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Prob<1> p;
    p.solve(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Does the problem number really need to be a template?  If you just made it a class member it would be trivial to store `Prob`'s in a container.

Comment: @NathanOliver I probably should have mentioned this but I want to use this as an abstract class so I can have many files with generic Prob functions and then the specific solution.

Comment: No STL container is suited to store heterogeneous types. If you have to do this, you'd have to use some form of type erasure.

Comment: You can still do that by making the problem number member of `Prob`.  I'm not seeing any benefit of making it a template parameter

Comment: @NathanOliver I think I see what you mean.  The only reason I wanted to make it templated is so I can have seperate files and not have to name the classes all Prob1, Prob2, Prob3 etc.  But I guess there is still a way to access the member functions of Prob without a template?

Comment: @Sean Why do problems need to be different types at all? The problem number/description can be part of the value of the class.

Comment: I can see I am probably going about this whole thing the wrong way.  I'll try and rethink this.  Thank you all for your input

Comment: We still do not see code for `solve`.

Comment: @Sean I would need to see more context on how you actually want to use this.  Could you pseudo code how you would like it to work?

Comment: @SeregyA I wanted solve to be different for each problem.  I am trying to make an abstract class and each templated problem would implement solve differently.

Comment: But there is no abstract class in your example. Abstract class is a class with at least one pure virtual function. I see none.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes I will add some more context.

Comment: @SergeyA I'll need to do some more research then I am still kind of new to C++ (Obviously haha).

Comment: @Sean It seems to me something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a57b314496df4d0d) is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance of a template class constitutes a different type. Hence, containers like `std::vector` cannot hold `Prob<ProbNum>` for different values of `ProbNum`.
If you know at compile time the number of `Prob<ProbNum>` instances you want, and the corresponding values of the template parameter `int ProbNum` you could store everything into a `tuple`. For example:

```
auto mycollection = std::make_tuple(Prob<1>(), Prob<2>());
```

A more general solution could be to define an abstract base class for `Prob`. Then you can manage to store a vector of `Prob<ProbNum>` objects, with inhomogeneous values of `int ProbNum`, if you define a vector of pointers to the base class. For this to work you must provide the interface in the base class, i.e., every member of `Prob<ProbNum>` that you want to access through the `vector` of the base class, must be `virtual` and already declared in the base class.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct base {
  virtual void print() const = 0;
  virtual ~base() = default;
};

template <int i>
struct derived : public base
{
  virtual void print() const { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> vec;
  vec.emplace_back(new derived<1>());
  vec.emplace_back(new derived<3>());
  vec.emplace_back(new derived<5>());
  for (auto& el : vec)
    el->print();

  return 0;  
}
```

The variable `vec` is essentially a vector of pointers to objects of type `derived<i>`, with inhomogeneous values of `i`. Because `base::print()` is virtual, it correctly resolves to the  corresponding method of the `derived<i>` class. 
Notice that I used a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to avoid memory leaking.

Also, it is important to declare `virtual` the destructor of `base`, see the discussion [Why should I declare a virtual destructor for an abstract class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270917/why-should-i-declare-a-virtual-destructor-for-an-abstract-class-in-c).

Comment: Thank you this is more along the lines of what I was looking for, just didn't give enough context at first.  Thank you!